# Stored Procedure and XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, xml, stored-procedures

I get this error:

```
The error description is 'Only one top level element is allowed in an XML document.'.
Could not find prepared statement with handle 0.
The XML parse error 0xc00ce555 occurred on line number 1, near the XML text "<value1>34</value1><value1>33</value1><value1>32</value1>".
The statement has been terminated.
```

This is Stored Procedure call:

```
 public bool HideFromList(string commentList, bool state)
{
//commentList =<values><value1>34</value1><value1>33</value1><value1>32/value1></values>
  using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(this.ConnectionString))
 {
       SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("VisibleFromList", cn);
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@XMLDoc", SqlDbType.Xml).Value = commentList;
       cmd.Parameters.Add("@state", SqlDbType.Int).Value = state;
       cn.Open();
       int ret =  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

       return (ret == 1);
 }
```

}

This is my Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.VisibleFromList
(
    @XMLDoc   xml,
    @state     BIT
)

AS
BEGIN


DECLARE @docHandle int
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @XMLDoc 


UPDATE tbh_Comments
SET Visible = @state WHERE 
CommentID IN (SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@docHandle, '/values/value1', 2) WITH (value1 INT '.'))


END
```

But If I Modify SP with embedded input string it does work:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.VisibleFromList
(
    @XMLDoc   xml,
    @state     BIT
)

AS
BEGIN


DECLARE @docHandle int
EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, 
'<values>
 <value1>33</value1>
<value1>34</value1>  
</values>'

UPDATE tbh_Comments
SET Visible = @state WHERE 
CommentID IN (SELECT * FROM OPENXML(@docHandle, '/values/value1', 2) WITH (value1 INT '.'))


END
```

How to make it work with input parameter?

Comment: Do you must use SQL 2000? If not, use the native SQL XML methods instead of XML prepare document

Comment: what do you mean native SQL XML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you positive your commentList is as you describe?

```
//commentList =<values><value1>34</value1><value1>33</value1><value1>32/value1></values>
```

If your list is indeed similar to that, it should work.

According to your error, it appears the `<values>` element may not exist:

```
near the XML text "<value1>34</value1><value1>33</value1><value1>32</value1>".
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you convert your procedures to use [XML Data Type Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190798.aspx). Unlike the sp_prepare_document stuff, these are implemented natively by the SQL engine and they interact better with queries, produce better error messages and you [don't run the risk of leaking document handles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260386(SQL.80).aspx).

So in your procedure you could do something like:

```
declare @XMLDoc xml;
select @XMLDoc =N'<values>
 <value1>33</value1>
<value1>34</value1>  
</values>';


UPDATE tbh_Comments
SET Visible = @state WHERE 
CommentID IN (
    SELECT v.value('.', 'INT') as CommentID
    FROM @XMLDoc.nodes('/values/value1') t(v))
```

Comment: In my experience yes, is faster most times.

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing some kind of looping I've found doing it like this is helpful:

```
XElement entityListElement = new XElement("values");
XElement entityElement = new XElement(
                    "value",
                    new XElement("value1", "15"));
entityListElement.Add(entityElement);
```

And then pass in entityListElement.ToString().

This also makes it (arguably) easier to make changes and has .NET do the XML generation for you.

Comment: Do you pass entityListElement to store procedure as XML parameter?
Because it gives an error: 
Object must implement IConvertible.

Comment: I added how I call it in code, since I noticed it was different than yours. I don't know if that would cause an errors though... I'm also using System.Xml.Linq for the XElements, if that helps.

Comment: I was stupid and only recently realized you weren't using LINQ. You can use .ToString() as I edited above to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.VisibleFromList (
    @XMLDoc   xml,
    @state     BIT )

AS BEGIN


DECLARE @docHandle int EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @docHandle OUTPUT, @XMLDoc 


 UPDATE tbh_Comments SET Visible = @state WHERE  CommentID IN (SELECT * 
 FROM OPENXML(@docHandle, '/root/values/value1', 2) WITH (value1 INT '.'))


END
```